# Codeception unit tests - error Class 'Dog' not found

Tags: php, phpunit, tdd, codeception

I'm using Codeception to TDD the development of a simple application in PHP. I've created my first unit test called DogTest.php with a simple assertion, but it's complaining about not being able to find the Dog class.

I have created a Dog.php file in the root directory, and also placed it under /src, but neither is working. I think this is either a namespace issue or an autoloader issue, but the Codeception documents (and the various TDD guides I've looked at) have this important detail missing.

Can someone please advise on how to get my DogTest to detect the Dog class?

Comment: using composer, yes?

Comment: yes, I'm using composer

Comment: i've added an answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your composer.json, make sure you have added autoloading configuration. As an example:

```
"autoload":{
        "psr-4":{
            "Del\\":"src/"
        }
}
```

Every file in src should have namespace `Del`. For instance, `src/Blank.php` would look like:

```
<?php

namespace Del;

class Blank
{

}
```

Whereas `src/Http/Client.php` would have namespace `Del\Http`.

Once added, run `composer dumpautoload` to generate the class maps. Your classes should now autoload without problems.

See my Blank starter project with codeception test for more info.

https://github.com/delboy1978uk/blank

Comment: Thank you for pointing that it has something to do with the composer. Good day Sir.